# Getting error while printing Hashmap using scanner classes of Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.scanner

I am currently writing a program to which sets the dynamic hashmap limit and ask user to enter key , values and then read the hashmap..

below is my code: where I have create 3 sepeate methods to read data from hashmap

```
package ToRemoventhHashmap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import codingInerviewQuestions.programToRemoveTheDuplicate;

public class nthElementRemoval {
    String readInput,dataInput1,dataInput2;
    Integer limitValue;
    public Integer specifyHashmapLimit() {
        Scanner dataInput1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter hashmap limit");
        limitValue = dataInput1.nextInt();
         dataInput1.close();
        return limitValue;
    }
    
    public HashMap<Integer,String> dataInputHashmap() {
        HashMap<Integer,String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        Scanner dataInput2 = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter key Values in Hashmap");
         for (int i = 0; i < limitValue; i++) {
                Integer a = dataInput2.nextInt();
                String b = dataInput2.next();

                hmap.put(a, b);
            }

        // limitValue = dataInput2.nextLine();
         dataInput2.close();
         return hmap;
    }
    
    public void  readHashmapData() {
        System.out.println("Hashmap key valuues are:");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> m : dataInputHashmap().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
        }
        
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        nthElementRemoval nthRem = new nthElementRemoval();
        System.out.println("hashmap limit specided is"+ nthRem.specifyHashmapLimit());
        nthRem.dataInputHashmap();
        nthRem.readHashmapData();
        
        
        

    }

}
```

After running this I am getting below error:

```
Enter hashmap limit
2
hashmap limit specided is2
Exception in thread "main" Enter key Values in Hashmap
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at JavaT/ToRemoventhHashmap.nthElementRemoval.dataInputHashmap(nthElementRemoval.java:25)
    at JavaT/ToRemoventhHashmap.nthElementRemoval.main(nthElementRemoval.java:50)
```

Could you help me how to fix this ?

Comment: Don't close the `Scanner` associated with `System.in`.

Comment: similar to [NoSuchElement using scanner twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23352098/85421) (almost 10 years old) or [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava.util.scanner%5Dnosuchelement) if searching for `[java.util.scanner] nosuchelement` (must read one or two before finding a match)