# Common way to use System.in several times without closing

Tags: java, bufferedreader, system.in

I have a console menu that has to read inputs a few times in different methods. I use a `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))` to do that. But if this reader is closed in a method it's not useable/openable again because of `System.in`.

To solve this problem one possibility is to `static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` so it's usable several times in different methods with `Main.br.readLine();`.

Is this a good way or are there much better methods?

Comment: Here is your answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962082/close-scanner-without-closing-system-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `BufferedReader` into your method(s) (or make it a shared field), that way you don't have to re-create it. Also, you are correct that closing `System.in` (or something wrapping `System.in`) will cause you issues. Instead of

```
public void foo()
```

something like

```
public void foo(BufferedReader reader)
```

Comment: So a `static BufferedReader...` or passing it around is a legal way and is both recommended?

Comment: `static` would make it a class level field.... it might be an instance field. Of course both are legal. As for recommended, I would prefer making it an argument (Java is pass by value, but the value of an `Object` instance is a reference).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will pass it to the methods which need it. That seems a good way.