# How to close a Scanner object inside a try loop without closing System.in?

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

```
 public static int take1(){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      while(true){
          try{
              System.out.print("\nHow many coloms you want = ");
              return in.nextInt();
          }
          catch(Exception e ){
              System.out.println("Sorry,Please enter only no.");
              in.next();
          } 
      }  
  }
```

how to close the scanner object , if i close this object using finally or try with resources it also closes System.in , and i cant read from stream more than once. what is the best method to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to close it? Is it just because there is a compiler warning?

Comment: what you want to achieve

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close Scanner without closing System.in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962082/close-scanner-without-closing-system-in)

Comment: If you are looking to call your method `take1` multiple times, don't create scanner object in this method. Create it where you are calling the `take1()` method and pass the scanner object as argument to your method, like `take1(Scanner sc)`, then close the scanner in your main method once you are done calling your method multiple times.

Comment: I want to close it because of compiler warning.

Comment: Thanks @Amit.rk3 , your approach worked for me , atleast now i dont see that compiler warning.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
finally {       
    sc.reset();
}
```

rather than  `sc.close();`

Answer (score 0):

put `finally` block  and close the open resource.

- **Java finally block** is a block that is used to execute ***important code such as closing connection, stream etc.***
- **Java finally block** is always executed whether exception is handled or  not.

  ```
   try
    {
        System.out.print("\nHow many coloms you want = ");
        return in.nextInt();
    } catch(Exception e ){
              System.out.println("Sorry,Please enter only no.");
              in.next();
     }finally{
              in.close();
     }
  ```

**EDITED AS PER Naman Gala**

check if exception occured then don't close it let it go for next loop util no. is entered otherwise close it.

```
public static int take1()
    {
        boolean isExceptionOccured=false;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.print("\nHow many coloms you want = ");
                isExceptionOccured=false;
                return in.nextInt();
            }
            catch(Exception e )
            {
                isExceptionOccured=true;
                System.out.println("Sorry,Please enter only no.");
                in.next();
            }finally{
                if(!isExceptionOccured){
                in.close();
                System.out.println("resource closed");
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: try-catch block is inside while loop.

Comment: Lets consider an exception occur then what will be the behavior of the program?

Comment: finally can not be used , because it will close the object (and also the System.in) in first iteration , which means it will throw an exception after first iteration.

Answer (score -3):

Use a variable inside try and then close. For example,

```
 public static int take1()
  {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      while(true)
      {
          try
          {
              System.out.print("\nHow many coloms you want = ");
              int i =  in.nextInt();
              in.close();
              return i;
          }
          catch(Exception e )
          {
              System.out.println("Sorry,Please enter only no.");
              in.next();
          }

      }

  }
```

This approach help you to close the object avoiding finally block.

Comment: This is bad. If there's an exception at `int i = in.nextInt();` or at `in.next():` the resource will never get closed.

Comment: Test the code and then give down vote after proper understanding.

Here if any exception occurs it will again asks the input. The program will not terminated unless a valid input is given.

Comment: Not if there's an exception at `in.next();` like I said in my comment.

Comment: Sorry , but i have tested it already and this approach does not work. the problem is not how you close the object , but once the object is closed it also closes System.in , which means if iterate for more than once ,it will throw an exception since we can not read from the closed input stream.