# Q: Help understanding closing Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.in

This is my working code.

```
public static void play() {

    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner myOtherScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!endCondition()) {
        //stuff
        shoot(myScanner);
    }

    keepPlaying(myOtherScanner);

    myScanner.close();
    myOtherScanner.close();
}
```

Method receiving `myScanner`:

```
static void shoot(Scanner sc) {
    int bullet;
    //Stuff

    bullet = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

    //More stuff
}
```

Method receiving `myOtherScanner`:

```
static void keepPlaying(Scanner myOtherScanner) {

    //Stuff

    int option = Integer.parseInt(myOtherScanner.next());

    //More stuff
}
```

Now what I don't understand:

If I close `myScanner` before calling `keepPlaying(myOtherScanner)`, `myOtherScanner.next()` will throw:

> NoSuchElementException

From what I've found it seems that closing a single Scanner closes `System.in`. Is that correct?

What is a good way to go around it?
Closing only at the very end?

Is it better to use a single `Scanner`?

Do I use the `Scanners` as global class elements?

Do I just not close the `Scanners`?

Answer (score 1):

A work around for this is to create your own `java.io.FilterInputStream`.

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new FilterInputStream(System.in) {
    public void close() throws IOException {
    }
});
```

Now when you call,

```
myScanner.close();
```

it closes only your `FilterInputStream` leaving the `System.in` open
<sup>([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19906353/2408342))</sup>.

---

Or you can just use a single `Scanner` as long as your application is single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.close()` on any resource like you are calling `myScanner.close();` it will close the resource and `in` stream as well.

Once the input stream is closed it cannot be reopened(as per javadoc) and since you are using same `System.in` stream in both scanners, once it is closed by `myscanner` it is not available for `myOtherScanner`, therefore it is giving Exception.